# Can someone tell me the contribution of s-, r-, and p-isotope processes to copper?

Tags: star, nucleosynthesis, astrochemistry

I have looked for relevant information in the paper [Chemical evolution with rotating massive star yields
II. A new assessment of the solar s- and r- process
components](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020MNRAS.491.1832P/abstract) before, but unfortunately, it only records the element gallium.

Comment: You mean it starts from Gallium.

Comment: Yes, the element preceding gallium was not present in that paper